# FileStreaming Saved File

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

This section of the code is not working. I'm trying to display the name saved in the file when the user has clicked n==1 into the textfield when the user has clicked n==0. It comes out blank for some reason I can't figure. Maybe I'm not calling the savedName return value properly?

```
    if (n == 1){    
        for(fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");!fn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");fn.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alphabet characters only.");
            fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");

        }
        writeToFile();
        for(sn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second name?");!sn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");sn.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alphabet characters only.");
            sn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second name?");
        }

    if (n == 0){
        String fullName = readFromFile();
        text.setText("Welcome " + fullName + ".");
        System.out.println(fullName);
    }
    }

private void writeToFile() {

    String nameToWrite = fn;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    //String savedName = "";
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        outStream.write(nameToWrite.getBytes());
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
            //savedName = br.readLine();

            text.setText("Welcome " + fn + ".");
            //System.out.println(savedName);            

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (null != outStream) {
            try {
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
   //return savedName;
}

private String readFromFile(){
    String savedName="";
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    savedName = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return savedName;   
}
```

Comment: Your condition `if (n == 0)` will never be true. Is this intentional? Properly indent your code to avoid such errors and make it more readable. It's unclear how first section of your code is executed.

Comment: OMG! I'M SO DUMB This error has been bugging me for hours and I never even noticed! Wooow I'm such an idiot!